# Site down because of checking permissions

Tags: mysql

In Mysql all my queries are stucked in "checking permissions" state.
Its a hostgator share site and they all are bunch of non techie guy and telling me , its apache issue.

[image]

Queries in this state are even stucking for more. how can i solve this issue.
Issue occures after mysql server was restarted by hostgator .

Its shared server how can i solve this or ask them to solve

Comment: ask them if you can be moved to a different server the one you are on right now is FUBAR.

Comment: what is FUBAR ?

Comment: @QuizMaster - Web search is truly your friend, for that acronym.